# Prove that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}1/x^n = 0$, $n ∈ \Bbb{N}*$

Tags: limits

Prove that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{x^n} = 0, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}^*$$

How do I prove this using just the definition of the limit?

Comment: no, it is stated as such

Comment: Well, just use the definition of the limit. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: Have you already proven that $\lim_{x\to\infty}1/x^n=0$? If so, you could use that and a limit theorem.

Comment: what values can $x$ take?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner any value in R

Comment: and when $x=5$ then is $\frac{1}{5^{-2}}=5^2$ and your Limit is not true.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It's $\lim\limits_{\color{red}{x}\to-\infty}$, what does setting $x=5$ mean? Moreover $n$ is supposed to be a positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $M>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. Then, if $x<-M,\ |1/x^n|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \dfrac{1}{ x^n}= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{(-x)^n}.$

$|x|^n \gt |x|$ ; for $|x| >1$,  $n \in \mathbb{Z+},$

implies  $ \dfrac{1}{|x|^n} \lt \dfrac{1}{|x|}.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, and  $M >1/\epsilon $.

For $ x  > M :$

$0< \dfrac{1}{|(-x)^n|} \lt \dfrac{1}{|x|} \lt 1/M \lt \epsilon.$

Comment: where do you use $\frac{1}{\vert x \vert ^n}<\frac{1}{\vert x\vert}$?

Comment: User1068603. Last line:$ |1/|(-x)^n|=1/|x|^n<1/|x|$.ok?

Comment: That is definitely okay. Thanks for clarifying